# CKEditor removing class from tag

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, flexslider

I've searched here and CKEditor docs under the Advanced Content Filter, but it's really confusing to me.

All I want to do is paste some simple Flexslider code into a CKEditor box, but when it saves, the class statement is stripped, leaving just the ul.

I can find lots of ideas for removing unwanted tags, but nothing to say allow class 'slider' on a ul element.

In my config.js, I tried:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.allowedContent = 'ul(slider)';
}
```

Also, tried extraAllowedContent, but no joy. Does anyone know how to do this please?

Comment: Please create a sample on jsfiddle using `extraAllowedContent` (your sample with `allowedContent` is plain wrong, because you don't even allow `li`) and a source from we could copy the Flexslider code. Otherwise we won't have any idea what you're trying to paste and into what editor.

Comment: Thanks @Reinmar, it's just a basic Flexslider code sample: [Code link here](http://jsfiddle.net/B4AFD/). I am pasting it into CKEditor V4.1.3 source view (also tried 4.2) and it saves ok and displays on my website correctly. But when I ask CKEditor to reload the data for editing, it strips `class="slider"` leaving `<ul>`. That's the only thing that is modified by CKEditor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is enough:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    extraAllowedContent: 'ul(slides)'
} );
```

You can check it on:

http://jsfiddle.net/6FnRf/

Copy that HTML, paste into editor and switch to source mode:

[image: correctly filtered HTML]

You can see that `slides` class was preserved when pasting and this means that it won't be stripped by CKEditor when you load the data (switch between source and WYSIWYG modes what equals to loading data). So if you're losing this class then something **outside** CKEditor is not working correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Reinmar for your assistance. That has fixed my issue.

I am using the CKEditor ASP.NET control, which complicated things a bit. So, for anyone else: You also need to add the ckeditor.js file manually to your page so that CKEDITOR.replace is defined. If your page has a masterpage, you'll need to add the code to your masterpage's onload event, not the page the editor is on.